# Should crond daemon process be run by root?

Tags: cron, cron-task

I've heard so much about individual processes should run as its own unprivileged user, yet the `crond` process is always run by `root`. My question is, should it? If so, is it considered "good practices" to have the `crond` process run by `root`, but individual cron jobs to always use unprivileged user then?

Comment: `crond` has to invoke commands on behalf of other users. How could it do that without being run by `root`?

Comment: @KeithThompson that's fair. But then how come there is a `cron` user in Alpine Linux, a minimal linux distro, out of the box? https://git.alpinelinux.org/cgit/aports/tree/main/alpine-baselayout/passwd?id=e409857fde32cd84d3f9de1c169336ee0d071e92#n15

Comment: I don't know. My guess is that the cron account owns files and directories used by crond (`/var/spool/cron` and so forth), but `crond` itself either runs as `root` or has similar privileges.